# Using Binary Constants (prefix 0b) In Code Processed by Splint

Tags: c, splint

According to the [GCC website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) and the [SDCC Manual<sub>§3.5.7</sub>](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/doc/sdccman.pdf), both GCC and SDCC allow the use of binary constants such as this one, where the decimal number 2 is represented: `0b0010`

Unfortunately, splint does not seem to handle this well resulting in a parse error, as shown below.

**binaryConstants.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>                                       
int main(){                                              
        int one = 0b0001;                                
        int two = 0x2;                                   
        int three = 3;                                   
        printf("B: %d\nH: %d\nD: %d\n", one, two, three);
        return 0;                                        
}
```

**Output**

```
$ splint binaryConstants.c
Splint 3.1.2 --- 19 Oct 2016

binaryConstants.c:3:18: Parse Error. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help
               parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
$
```

**Output with +gnuextensions**

```
$ splint +gnuextensions binaryConstants.c
Splint 3.1.2 --- 19 Oct 2016

Command Line: Setting +gnuextensions redundant with current value
binaryConstants.c:3:18: Parse Error. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help
                 parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
$
```

Is there a flag to allow this extension to C?